# How to set dbms_sql.Number_Table?

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

This is my PLSQL procedure:

```
procedure ChangeRequest(RequestID number,
                        MethodID number,
                        FieldIDs dbms_sql.Number_Table,
                        FieldValues dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table,
                        SessionID IRBiS_Const.TSessionID default null)
```

I want to set `FieldIDs dbms_sql.Number_Table` argument using `CallableStatement` in Java, but I don't know how. What is that thing? Array or what? Is there a setter method for that type in `CallableStatement`?

Comment: The short answer is "you can't". The longer answer is "you can't, but you can work around it (although it's far from simple)". See [this question and answer on OraFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/34783/0/). IMO you'd be better off writing a wrapper procedure with easy-to-pass types, call your wrapper proc from Java, and then have the wrapper proc call the "real" ChangeRequest procedure. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did it:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().doWork(new Work() {
                public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                    OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = null;
                    try {
                        callableStatement = (OracleCallableStatement) con
                                .prepareCall("begin PREQUEST.ChangeRequest(?,?,?,?,?); end;");
                        callableStatement.setInt(1, request_id);
                        callableStatement.setInt(2, method_id);

                        callableStatement.setString(5, sessionId);
                        callableStatement.setPlsqlIndexTable(3, field_ids,
                                field_ids.length, field_ids.length,
                                OracleTypes.NUMBER, 0);
                        callableStatement.setPlsqlIndexTable(4, fieldValues,
                                field_ids.length, field_ids.length,
                                OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 0);
                        callableStatement.execute();

                    } finally {
                        if (callableStatement != null) {
                            callableStatement.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

The main thing you should pay attention for is `prepareCall` method:

```
callableStatement = (OracleCallableStatement) con
                                    .prepareCall("begin PREQUEST.ChangeRequest(?,?,?,?,?); end;");
```

As you can see, it's PLSQL statement inside.